# Search functionality in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, controller

**I have jobplacement model and i want to implement search functionality which should be a keyword search i.e  i mean even if you type any keyword in search and if that is present in the db of jobplacement table it should show the results.**

Currently i am using following code which just matches 1 field i.e name of the company and category as in the params[:category].Following is tha code of my jobplacementcontroller/index action

```
if params[:search]
      @search_condition = "%" + params[:search] + "%"
      @searchresult = Jobplacement.where(['name LIKE ? and category = ?', @search_condition ,params[:category]])
else 
     @searchresult = ""
end
```

**Also in above code although i have given condition for category its not executing properly.When i do search it gives results that matches name field but its not evaluating params[:category] condition.it shows all the records even if they are not in the params[:category].**

---

Following are the fields in my jobplacement model :

```
t.string   "name"
t.string   "designation"
t.string   "qualification"
t.integer  "years_of_exp"
t.string   "location"
t.integer  "noofpost"
t.string   "jobprofile"
t.string   "salaryoffered"
t.string   "contactperson"
t.string   "employmenttype"
t.text     "address"
t.string   "city"
t.string   "state"
t.string   "country"
t.integer  "contactno"
t.string   "website"
t.text     "aboutcompany"
```

**so when i enter any keyword in search if that matches with data of any field it should return that data.How can i do this... 
How can i solve this params[:category] error and how can i do keyword search that matches any record present in the database of jobplacement model not just 1 field.**

Answer (score 0):

check out [Thinking Sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/quickstart.html), it has solutions to your problems and has more features like sub string search, wild char support and more

Answer (score 0):

using the squeel gem http://erniemiller.org/projects/squeel/
you can simply do:

```
terms = params[:search].split 
Jobplacement.where {name.eq(params[:category]) & (name.like_any(terms) | designation.like_any(terms) | qualification.like_any(terms) <...>) }
```